# Jenkins prints sensitive variable on failure

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Currently have an ssh key stored within a variable, I then pass that to a jenkins library in order to do some other processing. Issue is, if the call to the library code fails, it consoles out the contents of the variables passed into the library which is my private key - not ideal.

Any idea how I stop this from happening?

```
withCredentials([
          sshUserPrivateKey(
          credentialsId: 'keyid',
          keyFileVariable: 'keyFile')
          ]){
               libraryCode(readFile(keyFile))
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide credentials from output just use mask password plugin.